# Expected value as well as variance of observing a TH string in coin flips

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I'm working with a problem where I need to calculate the expected value and the variance of the amount of coin flips needed until we observe a a "TH" - string in a coin flip experiment.

In order to calculate the variance, one can use that $E[X^2] - E[X]^2 := Var(X)$ if we let $X$ be the amount of coin flips before until we observe a TH - string.

So, first we calculate the expected value.

$$E[X] = E[X|H] p(H) + E[X|TT]p(TT) + E[X|TH]p(TH)$$

We notice that $E[X|H] = E[X] + 1$ and that $E[X|TH] = 2$. Furthermore, $E[X|TT] = E[X] + 2$

Therfore, we get $$E[X] := \tau = (\tau+1) /2 + (\tau+2)/4 + 2/4 = 3\tau/4 + 3/2 \Leftrightarrow \tau = 6$$

However, this doesn't feel right. I know, from a previous example, that the expected value of observing a "HH" string or "TT" - string is $6$, and by gut instinct, it should be more common to observe a "TH" string, thus making the expected value less. I don't really want to continue to calculate the variance from here until I really know what's going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the event $H$?

Comment: @leonbloy Getting a Head in coin flip.

Comment: First, you need to clarify this: in  $E[X|TT]$, does $X$ mean the additional flips needed after getting two $T$ ? Or the total (including those two $T$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mistake is here: $E[X | TT] = E[X] + 2$.
This equality is not true.
If we start with the string "TT" (or equivalently just "T"), then we already have some of the work done: the last value was T, so if we get a H straight away, we're done because we get "TH".
Instead, if we start afresh (i.e. $E[X]$), we first need to get a T and *only then* an H, so it will take longer.

---

Let $\mathbb{E}[X \mid s]$ denote the expected amount of *additional* coin flips from this point to get a "TH", conditioned to the fact that we have just observed the string $s$.
Correspondingly, let $P(s)$ denote the probability of observing the string $s$ from this point after the appropriate amount of coin flips.

Then: $$\mathbb{E}[X] = (1 + \mathbb{E}[X \mid H])P(H) + (1 + \mathbb{E}[X \mid T])P(T) = 1 + \mathbb{E}[X \mid H]P(H) + \mathbb{E}[X \mid T]P(T)$$

On one hand, we have $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid H]$, because if we get a head, we're no closer to our goal of observing "TH" than when we started, so the expected amount of (additional) coin flips is the same.

On the other hand:
$$\mathbb{E}[X \mid T] = 1 \cdot P(H) + (1 + \mathbb{E}[X \mid T]) P(T)$$
Indeed, if we get a head after having just observed a tail, then we are done because we have found a string "TH", and this took just one additional coin flip.
Otherwise, if we get a tail, we're back in the same situation, so in addition to this one coin flip we need $\mathbb{E}[X \mid T]$ more coin flips.
(Note that $\mathbb{E}[X \mid TT] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid T]$.)

Solving for $\mathbb{E}[X \mid T]$, we get $\mathbb{E}[X \mid T] = 1/P(H)$.

Plugging this back in the first equation, we get:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = 1 + \mathbb{E}[X]P(H) + 1/P(H) \cdot P(T)$$

Solving for $\mathbb{E}[X]$, we get $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1/P(T) + 1/P(H)$. (Notice that this expression is symmetric: if we switch $H$ and $T$, we get the same value. This makes sense because the probability of "TH" is the same as the probability of "HT".)

If the coin is fair, this means $\mathbb{E}[X] = 2 + 2 = 4$.